# how do i make my app run on 5.1.1 when it was made on iOS 6

Tags: ios

i get this when i build  my iPhone app on 5.1 when it was made for iOS 6

2012-07-12 21:30:35.959 TechnoGadget[2836:f803] The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.

dos anyone know how to fix this???

Comment: Have you tried implementing the window property in your app delegate? In other words, `@property (strong) UIWindow *window` Have never seen that error but it is the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 2):

LLVM 4.0 features include not requiring @synthesize for properties (it auto does this for you). Likely the iOS6's new include files follow that convention. Don't try to mix builds with the beta iOS version until it's closer to being done. There are now 3 different builds of Xcode each with different features.

Answer (score 1):

borrrden & ahwulf are on target. I added

```
    @synthesize window;
```

to AppDelegate.m and all is well :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you omitted the `@synthesize` portion of your property.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens here when I'm trying to compile code that I have edited in Xcode >= 4.5 LLVM 4.0, and I open it running Xcode 4.3.1 running LLVM 3.1. The older version doesn't know about handling @properties without @synthesize.